# How to encrypt data correctly?

Tags: c++, windows, cryptography

I have the following code. I'd like to add to this code a key `BYTE[]` and an IV `BYTE[]` too, to encrypt my data with. To do that i have to call `CryptImportKey` and `CryptSetKeyParam`.

So my questions are:
Where do i have to call theese two APIs? I think after `CryptDeriveKey`, and then use the output from `CryptImportKey` to encrypt my data. Am i right?
Can i somehow ensure that the result is correct encrypted? Should i make some other changes to make my code more secure?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct CryptStuff
{
 HCRYPTPROV* hProv;
 HCRYPTKEY* hKey;
 HCRYPTHASH* hHash;

 CryptStuff(HCRYPTPROV* hprov, HCRYPTKEY* hkey, HCRYPTHASH* hash) :
               hProv(hprov), hKey(hkey), hHash(hash) {}

  ~CryptStuff() 
   { 
     if ( *hKey ) CryptDestroyKey( *hKey );
     if ( *hHash ) CryptDestroyHash( *hHash );
     if ( *hProv ) CryptReleaseContext( *hProv, 0 );
   }
};

void EncryptData( TCHAR *lpszPassword, char *pbBuffer, DWORD *dwCount )
{
HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
HCRYPTKEY hKey = 0;
HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;

// create an instance of CryptStuff.  This will cleanup the data on return
CryptStuff cs(&hProv, &hKey, &hHash);

LPWSTR wszPassword = lpszPassword;
DWORD cbPassword = ( wcslen( wszPassword ) + 1 )*sizeof( WCHAR );

if ( !CryptAcquireContext( &hProv, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, 
                           CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT ) )
{
    return;
}

if ( !CryptCreateHash( hProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash ) )
{
    return;
}

if ( !CryptHashData( hHash, ( PBYTE )wszPassword, cbPassword, 0 ) )
{
    return;
}

if ( !CryptDeriveKey( hProv, CALG_AES_256, hHash, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey ) )
{
    return;
}

DWORD size = ( DWORD )strlen( pbBuffer ) / sizeof( char );
cout << "\nLength of string = " << size;
if ( !CryptEncrypt( hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, ( LPBYTE )pbBuffer, &size, BLOCK_SIZE ) )
{
    return;
}
cout << "\nEncrypted bytes  = " << size;
cout << "\nEncrypted text = ";
cout.write(pbBuffer, size);

if ( !CryptDecrypt( hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, ( LPBYTE )pbBuffer, &size ) )
{
    return;
}
cout << "\nDecrypted bytes  = " << size;
cout << "\nDecrypted text = ";
cout.write(pbBuffer, size);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/228786 . It depends on how you want to use your keys to decide if anything is secure or not. Key management is a huge topic where books are written about.

Comment: @owlstead: Yeah i know that, that's why i asked it here. Maybe someone can give me an advice, in which direction i should go. Basicly i am looking for the most secure encryption method. It doesn't matter how much i read about it, i can't fully understand it. I have a string and i like to encrypt it. Should i encrypt it with a password, or using a key or an IV or a hash? Or all four of them? Or somehow else? That's what i need help with.